# Unknown Floppy Drive detected

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, udev, floppy

After a reboot, Ubuntu (and Windows) detect an external floppy drive that isn't even there!
It's not a big problem to find a new floppy drive that I can't access, but it really looks strange in the file manager.

This drive is recognized as `/dev/fd0`, I wan't to know how can I force Ubuntu to re-detect each connected device and get rid of this strange issue as quickly as possible.

Thanks ..